# web.xml invalidates my session

Tags: java, xml, session

I'm trying to do an error-code handling page in my web.xml. If I placed the code in my webxml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/errorPage.html</location>
 </error-page>
```

My session would be invalidated after logging in. It only does this on error 404 codes since I tried it with 403, it didn't invalidate my session.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my webxml or my server?